# I get "Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully" when I try to pip3 install pymc3

Tags: pip, failed-installation, pymc3, requirements

I need to use the module pymc3, but when I try to install it, I get the following error :

[error printed screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2438w.png)
I've tried to install pymc to see if it makes a difference, but it doesn't. My python version is 3.12. Any suggestion to solve this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please, no screenshots of text! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Comment: When I try to copy paste the text from the terminal, I get an error because the indentation is wrong. I've tried to solve the problem by adding the indentation, but apparently it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
py -m pip install pymc3
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate scripts in python enviromment with

```
myenv\Scripts\activate

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install pymc3
```

If you still encounter errors, it may be due to missing packages. Try installing the following packages:

```
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib pandas
```

*You should paste the error text in console , don't put images

Comment: It does not work :(
And when I try to copy and paste the terminal text, I get an error and I can't post my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. When I downgrade to Python 3.11.7, it works. Thanks everyone.